# Prove $A^\alpha$ positive semi definite

Tags: optimization, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

[image]

So I'm trying to solve this question, and I'm having some trouble.

It seems that I can "guess" the eigenvalues and eigenvectors (trying this out for a few n's I've found the pattern), but there has to be a cleaner way of solving this.

What am I missing?

I've tried:

1. Characteristic polynomial - By proving that for all $\lambda_i$s to be positive, $\alpha\geq0$. 
   But I can't seem to get a nice closed solution
2. Decomposing this to the following form thinking it might bring me closer to a nice solution:
   $$
       \alpha x^T\cdot I\cdot x + 2x^T\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
       0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
       1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
       \vdots & 1 & 0 & 0\\
       1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
       \end{pmatrix}
   \cdot x
   $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $A^\alpha = e e^T + (\alpha-1) I$, with $e$ being a vector of ones.

Note that $A^\alpha$ is real, symmetric.

It is straightforward to compute the eigenvalues by noting that $e$ is an eigenvector, and any $y \bot e$ is an eigenvector.

Now translate this into the requirement that $A^\alpha \ge 0$.

Here is another way:

$x^T A^\alpha x = (\sum_x x_k)^2+(\alpha-1) \sum_k x_k^2 $.

We need $\alpha \|x\|_2^2 \ge \|x\|_2^2 - (e^T x)^2$, or
$\alpha \ge 1- {(e^T x)^2 \over \|x\|_2^2}$ (for $x \neq 0$, of course).

Hence we see that $A^\alpha \ge 0$ **iff** $\alpha \ge 1- (e^T x)^2$ for all unit vectors $x$ **iff** $\alpha \ge 1$.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. Thanks.
But is there a less elegant solution that would've gotten me this answer?

Comment: I added a slightly different approach above. (Note: If $\alpha=1$ then $A^\alpha$ is not of full rank.)

Comment: Thanks! I was so close to the 2nd one. Oh well :)